# Never hide folders in fancytree filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am using the fancy tree filter plugin http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-ext-filter.html. I have the **mode: "hide"** set since I want to hide the unmatched nodes. Is it possible to never hide the folders?

I thought I can achieve this by adding a custom filter but I must be doing something wrong as the filter does not seem to take affect.

The code for the custom filter I am trying currently -

```
    //tree initialized before this step
    var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");
    searchText = $('#searchText').val().replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    var rex = new RegExp(searchText, 'ig');

    tree.filterNodes(function(node) {
        if(node.isFolder() ) {
            return "skip";
        }
        var match = rex.test(node.title);
        return match;
    });
```

Can anyone please point what I am doing wrong? Please let me know if you need any details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured it out. For anyone else who has the same requirements, I used the following code -

```
function(node) {
            var found = new RegExp(match, "i").test(node.title);
            if(node.isFolder() ) {
                return true;        //always match a folder
            } else {
                return found;  // otherwise match the nodes only
            }
        }
```

Also needed to set the leavesOnly value to false. Please note that the counter value will be wrong, but it was not required in my case.